Landaus&Lifshitz's derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations
Let $ L\colon\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ be a function (a "Lagrangian"), and let
$$
S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q(t),\dot q(t),t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
for any curve $ q\colon I\to \mathbb R $ defined on an interval $ I = \left[t_1,t_2\right] $ (the "action").
Suppose now that for any curve $ \delta q\colon I\to \mathbb R $ such that $ \delta q(t_0) = 0 = \delta q(t_1) $ then $ S[q]\leqq S[q + \delta q] $. At this point on the book (Landaus&Lifshitz, Course of Theoretical Physics, vol. 1) the following remark is made:

When the difference
$$
S[q + \delta q] - S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q + \delta q,\dot q + \delta\dot q,t)\,\mathrm dt - \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q,\dot q,t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
is expanded in powers of $ \delta q $ and $ \delta\dot q $ in the integrand (?), the leading terms are of the first order. The necessary condition for $ S $ to have an extremum is that these terms (called the first variation, or simply the variation, of the integral) should be zero (??).

I don't get where the authors are going. I would first notice that
$$
S[q + \delta q] - S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\bigl(L(q + \delta q,\dot q + \delta\dot q,t) - L(q,\dot q,t)\bigr)\,\mathrm dt\text{.}
$$
I would then write
$$
L\bigl(q(t) + \delta q(t),\dot q(t) + \delta\dot q(t),t\bigr) - L\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) = \mathrm dL\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr).\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr) + \sigma\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr)
$$
where
$$
\mathrm dL\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr).\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr) = \delta q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) + \delta\dot q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)
$$
is the differential of $ L $ at the point $ \bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) $ evaluated at the increment $ \bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr) $, and $ \sigma $ is a function that goes to zero quite fast.
At this point I would integrate this relation as in
$$
\begin{align}
S[q + \delta q] - S[q] &= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\delta q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) + \delta\dot q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)\right)\,\mathrm dt + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sigma\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr)\,\mathrm dt\\\\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta q(t)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) - \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}\right\rvert_{\tau = t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)\right)\, \mathrm dt + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sigma\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr)\,\mathrm dt\text{,}
\end{align}
$$
where in the last step I used integration by parts.
But now how do I deduce the E-L equations following Landau's advice?

The second integral is zero. For the first integral to be zero for any $\delta q(t)$, the parenthesis has to be zero. That's the E-L equation

By "the second integral" you mean $ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sigma\bigl(\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),t\bigr), \mathrm dt $? If so, why is it zero?

Btw, it's not clear to me why the integral
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta q(t)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) - \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}\right\rvert_{\tau = t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)\right), \mathrm dt
$$
evaluates to zero for every $ \delta q $ if and only if
$$
S[q + \delta q]\geqq S[q]
$$
for every $ \delta q $. Why is it so?

The integral is linear in $\delta q$ so you can consider both $\delta q$ and $-\delta q$ and since the integral is $\geq 0$ for small enough perturbations where $\sigma$ is negligible, we find that the integral is both $\geq0$ and $\leq 0$ and hence $=0$

I'll try to answer my own question, at least partially.
After some thought I came to the conclusion that the following is the right framework in which to interpret the words of Landau.
Definition. A normed affine space is just an affine space $ \mathcal X $ whose vector space of translations $ \Gamma $ comes equipped with a norm.
In our case we can fix some $ q_1,q_2\in \mathbb R $ and declare $ \mathcal X $ to be the space of all the paths $ q\colon I\to \mathbb R $ such that $ q(t_1) = q_1 $ and $ q(t_2) = q_2 $. Then $ \Gamma $ is the vector space of all the loops $ \delta q\colon I\to \mathbb R $ such that $ \delta q(t_1) = 0 = \delta q(t_2) $. I admittedly have no clue about what norm I should put on $ \Gamma $.
Definition. Let $ f\colon \mathcal X\to \mathcal Y $ be a function between two normed affine spaces. Given $ x\in X $, the differential of $ F $ at $ x $ is defined in the obvious way as the unique bounded linear map $ \mathrm df(x)\colon \Gamma\to \Delta $ between the corresponding normed spaces of translations such that
$$
f(x + \delta x) - f(x) = \mathrm df(x)\cdot \delta x + \sigma(\delta x)
$$
for every $ \delta x\in \Gamma $, where $ \sigma $ is a function defined on $ \Gamma $ such that $ \lvert\sigma(\delta x)\rvert/\lVert \delta x\rVert\to 0 $ whenever $ \delta x\to 0 $.
Of course, in our case the function $ f $ is the action functional $ S $ mapping a $ q\in \mathcal X $ to the action $ S[q] $.
Definition. A critical point of a function $ f\colon \mathcal X\to \mathcal Y $ between normed affine spaces is a point $ x\in \mathcal X $ such that $ \mathrm df(x) = 0 $.
Now, I didn't check that this holds, bu it seem obvious to me that given $ \delta x\in \Gamma $ then something like
$$
\mathrm df(x)\cdot \delta x = \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0}f(x + \epsilon\delta x)
$$
should be true. If I am right, we can then claim the following.
Lemma. A point $ x\in \mathcal X $ is a critical point of a function $ f\colon \mathcal X\to \mathcal Y $ between normed affine spaces if and only if
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0}f(x + \epsilon\, \delta x) = 0
$$
for every $ \delta x\in \Gamma $.
I think that at this point we can state and prove out main theorem.
Theorem. A path $ q\in \mathcal X $ is a critical point of the action functional $ S\colon \mathcal X\to \mathbb R $ if and only if the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}(q(t),\dot q(t),t) - \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}\right\rvert_{\tau = t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}(q(\tau),\dot q(\tau),\tau) = 0
$$
holds for every $ t $.
Proof. Suppose $ q $ is a critical point, i.e., suppose that
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0}S[q + \epsilon\delta q] = 0
$$
for every $ \delta q $. We can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0}S[q + \epsilon\delta q] &= \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L\bigl(q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta q(t),\dot q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta\dot q(t),t\bigr)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0} L\bigl(q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta q(t),\dot q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta\dot q(t),t\bigr)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\delta q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) + \delta\dot q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)\right)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \delta q(t)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) - \left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}\right\rvert_{\tau = t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)\right)\, \mathrm dt
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the second line I exchanged the derivative with the integral sign (?), in the third line I used the fact that
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\right\rvert_{\epsilon = 0} L\bigl(q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta q(t),\dot q(t) + \epsilon\, \delta\dot q(t),t\bigr) = \mathrm dL(q(t),\dot q(t),t)\cdot (\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),0)
$$
and the explicit expression of $ \mathrm dL(q(t),\dot q(t),t)\cdot (\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),0) $ which is
$$
\mathrm dL(q(t),\dot q(t),t)\cdot (\delta q(t),\delta\dot q(t),0) = \delta q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr) + \delta\dot q(t)\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}\bigl(q(t),\dot q(t),t\bigr)
$$
and in the last line I integrated by parts. Since $ \delta q $ is arbitrary, the thesis follows from there.
Vice versa, if the Euler-Lagrange equation holds, then repeating the argument above for an arbitrary variation $ \delta q $ results in $ q $ being a critical point. Q.E.D.
It remains to be shown that a critical point of a function $ f\colon \mathcal X\to \mathcal Y $ is actually an extremum of $ f $. It probably follows from the mean value theorem from the "multivariable" calculus in normed spaces idk.

In my opinion:
In an misguided attempt to simplify Landau has made things more complicated.

In and of itself it is correct to state that if you expand that difference in powers then the (remaining) leading terms are of first order.
For example: in the Feynman Lectures, Volume II, chapter 19, the Principle of Least Action Feynman makes use of that leading-terms-are-first-order property.
However, for the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation making use of that property is not a necessity. In my opinion it was ill advised of Landau to proceed that way; compared to the usual treatment it makes things even more opaque.
The thing is: when working with infinitisimals the proper way is to keep carrying them. The step of taking the limit of the infinitisimal going to zero should be the last step of a sequence of steps, not an intermediate step.

My recommendation is that you seek out other sources for derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation.
There is for instance the derivation by Preetum Nakkiran:
Geometric derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation
Preetum Nakkiran capitalizes on the fact that the Euler-Lagrange equation is a differential equation.

(Other than that: on my stackexhange profile page there is a link to discussion on my own website.)
